# How to create the expected parameter group when creating an Aurora replicate?

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-rds-aurora

I've got an RDS Postgres 12 database, and I would like to create an Aurora read replica for it (and eventually promote it to master). The problem is that when I do this it's asking me to select a "DB cluster parameter group". For some reason the only option in there is for Postgres 14:

[image]

I've tried creating that parameter group under the "Parameter group" tab, but whatever I create doesn't show up in that dropdown. And under "Option groups" it doesn't let me create one for Postgres.

Any idea what needs to be done here? How can I get it to display the Postgres 12 parameters here?